# Bootstrap Navbar transparent and then solid after clicking the toggle icon on mobile view

Tags: navbar

On mobile view bootstrap navbar is transparent but when I click on the toggle icon it keeps being transparent.[I don't like how it looks. I want it to be solid when I click and scroll down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPnE0.png) This is my CSS:

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 80.5%;
}

.custom-item {
    color: #9b9a9a;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.custom-item:hover {
    color: #cacdd8;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.custom-item-scrolled {
    color: #fffcfc;
}

.brand-style {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.custom-nav {
    background: rgb(96, 45, 46);
}

.brand-style {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.custom-brand {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar {
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

The html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <span class="brand-style brand-gradient">
                   BLOG 2.0
                </span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#blog-navbar" aria-controls="blog-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="blog-navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="fs-4 nav-link custom-item">China</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="fs-4 nav-link custom-item">Japan</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="fs-4 nav-link custom-item">Korea</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="fs-4 nav-link custom-item">Taiwan</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link custom-icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="#ffff" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-3">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link custom-icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="#ffff" class="bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Search for">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Also i create this function to change the color of the nav bar when i scroll down

```
const navEl = document.querySelector('.navbar');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 56) {
        navEl.classList.add('custom-nav')
    } else if (window.scrollY < 56) {
        navEl.classList.remove('custom-nav')
    }
})
```

Could you please help me get it sorted?